# How to include key exchange algorithms required to connect to router using OpenSSH client?

Tags: router, ssh, openssh, cipher

With OpenSSH_8.9p1 for Windows, I'm trying to connect to a NuCom router NC-WR764TGV:

```
ssh user@192.168.1.1
```

Output:

> Unable to negotiate with 192.168.1.1 port 22: no matching key exchange method found.
> Their offer: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,kexguess2@matt.ucc.asn.au

Thus I tried:

```
ssh user@192.168.1.1 -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

Output:

> Unable to negotiate with 192.168.1.1 port 22: no matching host key type found.
> Their offer: ssh-rsa

Then:

```
ssh user@192.168.1.1 -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,+ssh-rsa
```

Output:

> Unsupported KEX algorithm "ssh-rsa"
> command-line line 0: Bad SSH2 KexAlgorithms '+ssh-rsa'.

With ssh on my linux clients I had identical results. How can I talk to this router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"ssh-rsa" is not a key exchange algorithm – it is a public-key signature algorithm and goes in the `HostKeyAlgorithms` and/or `PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms` lists (the former to accept RSA-SHA1 signatures from the server during host verification, the latter to send RSA-SHA1 signatures *to* the server during user pubkey authentication)

(Note also that the `+` or `-` flags can only be specified once for the entire list – they are not repeated for individual items.)

For really ancient devices that OpenSSH no longer supports, use the `plink` SSH client from PuTTY.